# System.ArgumentNullException for Xamarin.Forms using StreamReader

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

In `public ScenarioPage()` of `ScenarioPage.cs` I have the following code to read from a json file:

```
var assembly = typeof(ScenarioPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly; 
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("firstSession.json");

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) // System.ArgumentNullException
      {
          var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
          List<SessionModel> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SessionModel>>(json); 
          foreach(SessionModel scenario in data)
           {
                    
              label.Text = scenario.title;
              break;
           };

       }
```

I am getting an ArgumentNullException for the `stream` input. `firstSession.json` is in the same folder as `ScenarioPage.cs`, and it is set as an embedded resource. It seems like Visual Studio is not recognizing that my json file is there. Is this is a bug? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Set CopyToOutput directory to Always for the json file. And check the Directory.GetCurrentPath. Check whether the file is there on not on the path

Comment: The CopyToOutput directory is on Always. How can I check the Directory.GetCurrentPath?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory

Comment: It says ```The current directory is /```. How do I check whether the file is on that path?

Comment: File.Exists method

Comment: ```string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string target = @"c:\temp";
                Console.WriteLine("The current directory is {0}", path);
                string curFile = @"c:\temp\firstSession.json";
                Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");``` outputs ```File does not exist```

Comment: are you able to solve the issue?

Comment: No. Visual Studio is not recognizing that my file is in the folder. I still don't know why this is happening

Comment: I suggest you call `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` and look at the results in the debugger, to see what the actual resource name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you put the Json File, I put it in the Json File in the root Of PCL like following screenshot.
[image]

Then use following code to read the Json File.

```
  void GetJsonData()
        {
            string jsonFileName = "firstSession.json";
            ContactList ObjContactList = new ContactList();
            var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list    
                ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(jsonString);
            }
          
            EmployeeView.ItemsSource = ObjContactList.contacts;
           
        }
```

And here is running GIF.

[image]

I update my demo to you. you can test it
https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/PlayMusicInBack.zip

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: This is working if I transfer the files to a new project, but unfortunately it still isn't working in my other project. I think it might be a bug